# How to use ld to link obj files produced by gcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

These days I'm reading APUE and setting up the Makefile myself instead of using the existing .mk Makefile provided by the book's website. My Makefile goes like this:

```
CC=gcc
LD=ld
CC_FLAGS= -c -I ./include/ -Wall -Wextra
LD_FLAGS= -e main -lc
LIB_OBJS= ./lib/*.o #There'are about 30 .c files in lib, \
most of which are wrap of error handling routines or simplified APIs. \
So I don't copy them all in the code block

all: 

ls: ls.c $(LIB_OBJS)
        $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) -o ls.o ls.c
        $(LD) $(LD_FLAGS) -o ls ls.o ./lib/error.o

$(LIB_OBJS):
        cd ./lib; \
        make

clean:
        cd ./lib; \
        make clean
        rm ./ls
```

The Makefile in ./lib is pretty much similar to this one as it just gcc -c all .c files in that directory and doesn't do any linking works. And the ls.c is the first piece of code in Chapter One which just list every element of the given dirent. 
My problem is, my Makefile CAN PRODUCE a executable without any error printed but this file is not executable at all. Whenever I ./ls with the x privilege, bash returns:

```
bash: ./ls: No such file or directory
```

But if I use gcc to link ls.o and ./lib/error.o together it works smoothly. So I wondered what's special in gcc's ld invoking. How do I do if I only use ld to link gcc produced stuffs? 
Thanks beforehand!

Comment: Use `$(MAKE) -C lib clean` instead of `cd ./lib; make clean`; and code `LIB_OBJS= $(wildcard lib/*.o)`  because `make` does not know about `*` otherwise.

Comment: Also, there is no good reason to link with `ld` instead of `gcc` (unless you are hacking your own *libc* and compiler tool).

Comment: Side note - "No such file or directory" on executable that actually exists likely means that there is no interpreter found to execute this file. You could verify it with `readelf -a <your program> | grep interpreter`. Interpreter specified with `-dynamic-linker` ld flag, however - if default one is broken, it isn't a good sign.

Comment: make can deal with the `*` wildcard just fine it just doesn't do anything with it at variable assignment time. It will, however, evaluate it when used in a rule body or prerequisite (but do so repeatedly instead of just once).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what toolchain you are using, but there are few default libraries that gcc pass to linker other than the ones you specify, for e.g. libc

Here is a part output of gcc with -v option which tells about linker step:

GNU assembler version 2.17.50.0.6-12.el5 (i386-redhat-linux) using BFD version 2.17.50.0.6-12.el5 20061020
 **/usr/libexec/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/collect2** --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_i386 --hash-style=gnu -dynamic-linker **/lib/ld-linux.so.2** -o y.o /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../.. /tmp/ccS39C4x.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../crtn.o

Comment: Good, but technically it is not only *libraries* but some *object files* (the `crt*.o`) which are linked by `gcc`

Comment: crt*.o are files used for program stub. At the end of this [cross compiler HOWTO](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/base/embedded/handbook/?part=1&chap=2) their functionalities were explained. I thought these stuff were assembly codes inserted by gcc so I don't expect they are the causes of the problem. Thanks to the answer.